Python : win32print - data does not leave the print queue
Below is a small code in Python where I am trying to send a text to a specific printer and the printout is stuck in the printer queue.
Can anyone tell me if there is anything else I need to add to the code?
Note: The printer is on the network and working perfectly.
I'm using Windows 11 and my Python version is Python 3.12.3
import win32print

v_printer_handle = win32print.OpenPrinter( "Brother DCP-L5652DN Printer" )

v_job_name      = "My Job"
v_file_to_print = None 
v_data_type     = "RAW"

v_DocInfo = ( v_job_name, v_file_to_print, v_data_type )

win32print.StartDocPrinter( v_printer_handle, 1, v_DocInfo )

win32print.StartPagePrinter( v_printer_handle )

raw_data = bytes( "This is a test printing python !", "utf-8" )

v_bytes = win32print.WritePrinter( v_printer_handle, raw_data ) 

print( "Bytes Sent: ", v_bytes )

win32print.EndPagePrinter( v_printer_handle )

win32print.EndDocPrinter( v_printer_handle )

win32print.ClosePrinter( v_printer_handle )


Appreciate any help
Thanks
I've already tried other functions like os.start and shellexecute without success! I have two needs, send any text or any file to a specific printer!
